# In a commandLink, I use <f:param...> and got a null parm in my MBean

Tags: jsf-2, parameters

In my jsf I use :

```
<f:param name="parm1" value="#{templateGP01MB.stringAnnId}" />
```

and receive a null parameter in my Managed Bean.

If I write the following :

```
<f:param name="parm1" value="5" />
```

I got 5 in my MBean.

Here is my code for my JSF:

```
                <p:imageSwitch effect="turnDown" speed="10000">  
                    <ui:repeat value="#{galerieFloMB.stringArray}" var="image" >                         
                        <h:commandLink value="Voir l'annonce correspondante" actionListener="#{templateGP01MB.actionListener}" action="#{templateGP01MB.action}" >
                            <!-- <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/download/#{image}" width="300" height="300" onclick="visualisationAnnonce('#{image}');" /> -->
                            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/download/#{image}" width="300" height="300" />
                            <f:attribute name="attributeName1" value="#{image}" />  
                            <f:param name="parm1" value="#{templateGP01MB.stringAnnId}" /> 
                        </h:commandLink> 
                    </ui:repeat>   
                </p:imageSwitch> 

            </h:form>
```

And here is my code for my MBean TemplateGP01MB.java:

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    photo = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("attributeName1");
    annonceEtendue = getAnnonceEtendueFacade().searchByPhoto(photo);
}

public String action() {
    return "visualisationAnnonce";
}
```

In the MBean VisualisationAnnonceMB.java, I got :

```
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String parm1 = params.get("parm1");
    Integer integerParm1 = Integer.parseInt(parm1);
```

And I got a Null pointer exeption cause parm1 = null...

Sure I am a newbie and I don't really understand evrything about jsf lyfecycle.
If someone can HELP me, it would be great :)

Thanks in advance
GLO

Comment: why are you mixing f:param and f:attribute? why don't you choose one of them and use it twice? it doesn't make any sense to mix them, and I'm not sure about this but is probably the reason why it is not working